# How to use RDF:label in protege

Tags: sparql, protege, rdfs

For the RDF labels I'm trying something really simple to show all the labels in my ontology , but even that its not working. Do you have any idea how I need to write any rdfs:label

SELECT ?subject ?label
WHERE { ?subject rdfs:label ?label }

Comment: "not working" is not a good description ... also, did you assign those labels **explicitly** to the entities in your ontology? What I mean, did you add those label annotations to the classes, properties and individuals?

Comment: by is not working I mean there is not results. I understand everything , but the RDFS: label its not explained anywhere . Even in the book whish I'm learning SPARQL  its not clear how to use it in protégé . As in my last question, you told me to use the RDFS, but I wasn't able, so I tried something really simple, with this query .

Comment: Please add an example of the ontology where this does not work - the problem might be in the data.

Comment: you have to add those annotation for the `rdfs:label` property in Protege - that's it. There is no magic behind, just add the data, then you can use SPARQL to query the data

Comment: @UninformedUser Hey , just a last question do you think because I didn't install the plugin pellet that's why its not working ?

Comment: Even when I try to add it , Protégé is telling me that there is no download available

Comment: So after some search I just downloaded the newest version of protégé because I think the 4.3 doesn't get any updates anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ?subject ?label WHERE { ?subject <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?label }
```

You could also maybe use a prefix like so:

```
PREFIX rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?subject ?label WHERE { ?subject rdfs:label ?label }
```

You can try out the queries by using the DBPedia endpoint:

https://dbpedia.org/sparql

To use existing predicates from other graphs you first have to include the reference to the predicate. Otherwise the query cannot find the correct predicate.